# Intellij/IDEA Switcher Key Map

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason my "Switcher" key mappings have changed recently.  Opening the terminal or switching to it was always done with the "t" key.  Now it maps to random number, sometimes 5, sometimes 8.  This sucks for obvious reasons.  Is there a remedy?

I did see a [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dONO.png) (not an accepted answer) to this question, but I wanted to try here again just in case there might be an update or someone knows the magic trick to configure it or revert it what it has been for what seems like years now.

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in IJ 2018.1 and 2018.2 EAP (only without colors https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192025), what's your version?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/eeR0rnr.png) in 2018.1.4.